# Can you recover an AES encryption key if you know the unencrypted content?

Tags: security, aes, encryption

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to find key to decrypt ciphertext by having the original plain text ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044701/is-it-possible-to-find-key-to-decrypt-ciphertext-by-having-the-original-plain-tex)

Suppose I have encrypted a string with AES256 and someone else knows the unencrypted content of that string. Given the encrypted string, would it be any easier for that person to recover the encryption key given that they know the original unencrypted string?

Thanks..

Comment: check this out: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/56870/compute-the-aes-encryption-key-given-the-plaintext-and-its-ciphertext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it shouldn't. If this was possible then AES would be susceptible to a [know-plain text attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack) making it non secure.`

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question. AES is not susceptible, plus the use of salt means that it's essentially impossible to know the plain text anyway.