# Get AES-128 key knowing the encrypted and original text

Tags: encryption, aes

Suppose I'm encrypting a data string:

> DATA: "This is my data!" (hex 54686973206973206d79206461746121)

with a key:

> KEY: "This is my key!!" (hex 54686973206973206d79206b65792121)

Using AES-128 I will get this result (in hex):

> RESULT: 425acf4117829a37be386995408ba1a9

Now, suppose that some one gets the DATA and RESULT strings. Is it possible to calculate the KEY with this information?

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to find key to decrypt ciphertext by having the original plain text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044701)  **Short answer:** *No.* AES is not vulnerable to a known-plaintext attack.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to find key to decrypt ciphertext by having the original plain text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044701/is-it-possible-to-find-key-to-decrypt-ciphertext-by-having-the-original-plain-te)

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know that what I'm asking calls known-plaintext attack. This is why I didn't find the answer. Thanks again!!

Comment: AES is also secure against "chosen-plaintext" attack, that is, even if the attacker can encrypt anything she wants and get the corresponding ciphertext, she will not be able to find out the key.